# sprintf outputs an extra string

Tags: c++

Using sprintf outputs an extra string, like "%x ...."

```
int main()
{   
    char *word_tmp = new char[0];
    char *word_all = new char[0];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        sprintf(word_tmp, "\nNumber:%d, Good Good!", i);
        sprintf(word_all, "%s%s", word_all, word_tmp);   
    }

    std::cout<<word_all;
}
```

The program works right, but outputs a string I have not output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arrays have zero-length, so the buffer `word_tmp` in not big enough to hold the result of the first call to `sprintf()`, which results in a buffer overrun. In this case, therefore, the behavior of your first call to `sprintf()` is undefined.

Apart from this, [if copying takes place between objects that overlap as a result of a call to `sprintf()` or `snprintf()`, the results are undefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html).

Finally, your function is leaking memory, because you do not call `delete[]` for arrays allocated with `new[]`.

You should use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to do what you are trying to achieve in a type-safe manner (credits to [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) for spotting problems with my previous attempt to produce a minimal fix for your program):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ss << "Number: " << i << ", Good Good!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx$176).

Comment: Most likely he doesn't want anything like that.  What does the magic number `256` mean, for example?  And the program is still full of undefined behavior: the violation of the `restrict` on the `sprintf` arguments, for example.  (Not to mention all of the violations of good coding practice: the use of `memset`, for example, where a simple initialization would do the trick; the use of `sprintf`; the use of `char []` when `std::string` would be more appropriate., etc., etc.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I agree. I just didn't want to change the OP's program completely, as that would not answer his question ("what is causing the weird behavior of my program?"). So I basically tried to "speak his language" to find a common ground, and possibly I failed to do so correctly. Of course I agree that using `std::string` is better, but that would make it impossible to use `sprintf`. Fine, I could show `std::stringstream` etc., but the OP probably needs to get there first.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually very surprised that this code doesn't crash... Your sprintf destination strings don't have enough space to place the data. And also I just typed man sprintf and read this:

```
C99  and  POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to sprintf(),
snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying to take place between objects 
that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the
supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer).
```

So your second sprintf is undefined in c99.

Also this is really strange that you use C++ new operator and use sprintf to append strings and insert numbers to string, when in C++ you have std::string and stings streams to do this in a safe way.

I think you need to read some books and understand what is going on in c and c++.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't guarantee a crash. IIRC, `new [0]` is required to return a non-null pointer, and is effectively implemented as if it were `new[1]`.  What _is_ doubtlessly happening is that he's corrupting the free space arena, and the program will probably crash if he were to do a `delete` (and probably if he were to try to allocate more memory).  Finally, with regards to the violation of `restrict`: that's probably why his output is not what he expects.

Comment: @JamesKanze I never told that undefined behavior equals crash. I just mentioned that I was surprised that program didn't crash. two bad memory writes were done that were expected to be null-terminated strings and overlapped null(?) terminated string copy was done (with some functions that can get that memory chunk for own needs). I'm pretty sure that is was quite possible, that some null terminators could be filled with some data and enough non null garbage after. (And here i even do not expect the instant segfault on first write).

Answer (score 0):

First, you never want to use `sprintf`.  It's almost impossible
to use correctly.  In this case, you're outputting it's value to
memory which doesn't exist, so you have undefined behavior.
(Just how much memory do you think `new char[0]` is going to
allocate?.  In the second `sprintf`, you're also inputting from
memory which doesn't exist—more undefined behavior, and
you're outputting and inputting from the same memory (supposing
that there was any memory), which is also undefined behavior.

Just forget about `sprintf` and array new:

```
std::string results;
for ( int i = 0; i != 5; ++ i ) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "Number: " << i << " Good Good!\n";
    results += s.str();
}
std::cout << results;
```

(I think that this is what you're trying to do.)

One final point: while it's almost never a real problem, the standard does require that the last character output to a text stream (like `std::cout`) be a `'\n'`.